# How to check elements in row of 2D array, store them, and compare them?

Tags: arrays, c

I've been trying to check elements in a row of an 2D array and store the elements in a variable so that I can use the variable for comparing. I'm lost between how to check the elements and store it in a variable.

I've written this much:

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main()
{
    int array1[10][10];
    int row, column, num, found = 0, passMark = 60, fail = 0;

    printf("How many rows and columns needed: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &row, &column);

    printf("\nHow many students marks you want to enter: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    printf("\nEnter %d students marks: ", num);

    for(int i=0; i<row; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<column; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &array1[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for(int i=0; i<num; i++)
    {
        // int passMark = array1[i][0];
        for(int j=1; j<num; j++)
        {
            if(array1[i][j] >= passMark)
            {
                passMark = array1[i][j];
            }
            /*else
            {
                min = array1[i][j];
            }*/
        }
        printf("\nYes!");
        // found = 0;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code example comments out the declaration and initialization of passMark. You then compare array[i][j] with the value in passMark. This code segment should not compile.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things wrong with the code.

1. You ask the user to input `row/column` but you have already declared an array of static size `10 * 10`.

   If you want the size to be determined by the user, you should use a dynamic array  and make use of `malloc()` and `free()`.
2. When you check, you start with `j = 1` skipping one mark, you should start from `0`.
3. You seem to be asking again how many student and how many marks per student you want to add, but you already got that information. The `rows` represent the student and `columns` represent the number of marks per student.

You should be looking for something like this, but again this is my guess, question is quite unclear.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int **array1;
    int row, column, num, found = 0, passMark = 60, fail = 0;

    printf("How many students and how many marks per student?\n");
    
    if (scanf("%d %d", &row, &column) != 2)
    {
        /* conversion failed */
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    array1 = malloc(row * sizeof(int *));
   
    if (array1 == NULL)
    {
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        array1[i] = malloc(column * sizeof(int));

        if (array1[i] == NULL)
        {
            /* allocation failed - exit / display error */
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

    }

    printf("\nEnter %d students marks: ", row);

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < column; j++)
        {
            if (scanf("%d", &array1[i][j]) != 1)
            {
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++, fail = 0)
    {
        printf("Student's %d grades:\n", i + 1);
        for (int j = 0; j < column; j++)
        {
            if (array1[i][j] >= passMark)
            {
                printf("Passed class %d with grade : %d\n", j + 1, array1[i][j]);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Failed class %d with grade : %d\n", j + 1, array1[i][j]);
                fail++;
            }
        }

        printf("Student %d failed %d classes", i + 1, fail);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Consider using a pointer to VLA. The whole allocation code would be: `int (*array1)[column] = malloc(row * sizeof *array1);`

Comment: I have tried and I got what I was looking for. Thanks for the help.